# Preventing Bed Resonance

Tags: bedroom, furniture, sex

This is somewhat similar to [this question](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/15533/how-to-prevent-bed-movements-noises-when-having-sex), but not exactly the same, because it's not about noise per se and I'm not the one causing it (yet). The floor of my apartment is very light (probably cheap) fake wood vinyl, and it's above a mostly-empty and not well insulated crawlspace, and is attached to one other apartment. And unfortunately, the way the building is set up places the two apartments' bedrooms right next to one another. So, whenever my neighbors perform some certain...oscillatory activities, I can feel the vibrations very distinctively from my bed.

What should I do to cut down on this? Would lowering my bed to the floor help? It is currently supported by six approximately 6 inch metal legs and on a box spring, on a hardwood floor (which I know is the real problem, but unfortunately I can't change that). Would it help to place the bed legs on a rug or something? What about a heavier bed-frame? It's currently resting on the thin metal rails that came with the mattress.

Also, should I assume that anything I do on my bed would be felt in the same way by the other tenants? If it's my bed that's causing the resonance effect, maybe I wouldn't need to worry about bothering them (unless they have the same kind I suppose). Or would whatever changes you recommend also cut down on this?

Comment: You cannot change the resonance of the building which is driving this.  Get them to put a box spring on cinder blocks would help.

Comment: You could always get them to break up. That would stop the oscillations. (That was a terrible suggestion! Forget I ever said it.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are directly above a crawlspace, you can add some support for the beam (bearer) supporting the floor joists under you. In the illustration, the centre beam would be the problem spot to check.

[image: Floor cross-section showing supports, and floor joist]

The best material to use is concrete cement blocks piled on top of each other to support the common wall separating your apartment from Casanova's. There might even be a support already there where the shims (grey part on top of supports) have become displaced. The support might have dropped, become dislodged, or be missing.

A car jack can boost and hold the beam temporarily while you fit the last parts of the support column into place before you lower the floor.

Try increasing the height about an inch the first time you jack up the floor. You can use dry wood shims for thicknesses less than concrete blocks.

Did it work? If it isn't perfect, Casanova will help test your work and you can modify the amount of support until it's solid and doesn't move during the most amourous activity.

It's not complex or hard. The heaviest thing will be a concrete block, one at a time. Take your time. Good Luck.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and cheapest would be to put some carpet squares under the bed posts (on the floor) - you could even double or triple them up - cut them into squares then glue them together to make them thicker.  I'd try that first before I even spoke to them about the noise!  (would you want to know that your neighbor could hear everything you were doing? hmmmm.) you can also probably buy some floor protector coasters made of a rubber-like material, which would work. Bed Bath and Beyond would have this kind of thing.
Also check whether the vibrations might not be coming through the headboard instead of the floor - if so, move slightly away from the wall!